# FreeIPA unable to create a replica

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I'm trying to create a replica of my single FreeIPA server to aid in migration and move to a clustered environment.

I spun up a CentOS host, enrolled it as a client to the ipa server, and added it to the group `ipaservers`.  I then ran `ipa-replica-install` after running `kinit` to login as admin.

```
Run connection check to master
Connection check OK
Disabled p11-kit-proxy
Configuring directory server (dirsrv). Estimated time: 30 seconds
  [1/41]: creating directory server instance
  [2/41]: configure autobind for root
  [3/41]: stopping directory server
  [4/41]: updating configuration in dse.ldif
  [5/41]: starting directory server
  [6/41]: adding default schema
  [7/41]: enabling memberof plugin
  [8/41]: enabling winsync plugin
  [9/41]: configure password logging
  [10/41]: configuring replication version plugin
  [11/41]: enabling IPA enrollment plugin
  [12/41]: configuring uniqueness plugin
  [13/41]: configuring uuid plugin
  [14/41]: configuring modrdn plugin
  [15/41]: configuring DNS plugin
  [16/41]: enabling entryUSN plugin
  [17/41]: configuring lockout plugin
  [18/41]: configuring topology plugin
  [19/41]: creating indices
  [20/41]: enabling referential integrity plugin
  [21/41]: configuring certmap.conf
  [22/41]: configure new location for managed entries
  [23/41]: configure dirsrv ccache and keytab
  [24/41]: enabling SASL mapping fallback
  [25/41]: restarting directory server
  [26/41]: creating DS keytab
  [error] CalledProcessError: CalledProcessError(Command ['/usr/sbin/ipa-getkeytab', '-k', '/etc/dirsrv/ds.keytab', '-p', 'ldap/ipa-apollo.lan.whitefamilyserver.com@WHITEFAMILYSERVER.COM', '-H', 'ldaps://ipa.whitefamilyserver.com'] returned non-zero exit status 9: 'Failed to parse result: Failed to decode GetKeytab Control.\n\nRetrying with pre-4.0 keytab retrieval method...\nFailed to parse result: Insufficient access rights\n\nFailed to get keytab!\nFailed to get keytab\n')
Your system may be partly configured.
Run /usr/sbin/ipa-server-install --uninstall to clean up.

CalledProcessError(Command ['/usr/sbin/ipa-getkeytab', '-k', '/etc/dirsrv/ds.keytab', '-p', 'ldap/ipa-apollo.lan.whitefamilyserver.com@WHITEFAMILYSERVER.COM', '-H', 'ldaps://ipa.whitefamilyserver.com'] returned non-zero exit status 9: 'Failed to parse result: Failed to decode GetKeytab Control.\n\nRetrying with pre-4.0 keytab retrieval method...\nFailed to parse result: Insufficient access rights\n\nFailed to get keytab!\nFailed to get keytab\n')
The ipa-replica-install command failed. See /var/log/ipareplica-install.log for more information
```

As you can see, the command fails.  It says it has insufficient permissions, but I don't see which permission to add to allow this command to work properly.

Yet when I run the command that failed manually, it succeeds.  So why does it fail during the install, but not when I run it manually?

```
[root@ipa-apollo mendicant]# ipa-getkeytab -k /etc/dirsrv/ds.keytab -p ldap/ipa-apollo.lan.whitefamilyserver.com@WHITEFAMILYSERVER.COM -H ldaps://ipa.whitefamilyserver.com
Failed to parse result: Failed to decode GetKeytab Control.

Retrying with pre-4.0 keytab retrieval method...
Failed to retrieve encryption type AES-128 CTS mode with 128-bit SHA-256 HMAC (#19)
Failed to retrieve encryption type Camellia-128 CTS mode with CMAC (#25)
Keytab successfully retrieved and stored in: /etc/dirsrv/ds.keytab
```

Extended downtime will not be an issue to try and fix this.

Comment: could you show what is in the log file /var/log/ipareplica-install.log?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

1. [On master]# ipa-replica-manage del  --clean --force
2. [On replica] Uninstall ipa-server-install --uninstall
3. [On Replica] Make sure to call "kdestroy -A" before ipa-replica-install.

Answer (score 0):

So you've clipped off the portion of your output that shows how the installation was invoked, but installing a replica takes a long time, and if you used sudo to run the installation, the typical timeout for sudo is 5 minutes. If the installation takes longer than 5 minutes (which it does), then you will lose permissions at that point in the installation process. So your options are either change the sudo timeout/requirement, or install using the root account so sudo is not required.